# Does the sign integral and limit exchange?

Tags: real-analysis

If $f_{n}(x),n=1,2,\cdots$ and $f(x)$are nonnegative real integrable functions .Moreover ,
assume $\forall x,\lim\limits_{n}f_{n}(x)= f(x)\  and \int\limits_{R}f_{n}(x)dx$ is nondecreasing.Is the equality $$\lim_{n}\int\limits_{R}f_{n}(x)dx=\int\limits_{R} f(x)dx$$
true? Why? 
Thanks.

Comment: If you had $f_n$ is non-decreasing, then it would follow by the monotone convergence theorem. I'm not sure whether you can apply it knowing that $\int f_n(x)dx$ is a non-decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If your integrals are over the entire real line, just let $f_n$ be zero except for a bump around $x = n$, say of width 1, and height $1 - 1/n$.  Then the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n$ will increase to the integral of the bump with height $1$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$ so $\int f = 0$.

Comment: The conclusion is true, however, if all the action is happening on a set of finite measure (ie. all the $f_n$'s are supported on the same bounded set). This would follow by applying Fatou's lemma in two different ways.

Comment: @Prahlad You should post this as another answer, because I think it would be appreciated to see that the result does hold in your setting (and why), to put into context exactly when this kind of result can hold and why/why not.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan And if some domination condition is fulfilled (otherwise, consider $f_n=n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$).

Comment: I am more will to put it in the context of probability theory.Assume $\{X_{n},\mathcal{F_{n}}\}$ is a nonnegative martingale,and $X_{n}\rightarrow X^*$(we always can change some elments whose measure is 0 to make it a r.v),thus $X_{n}\rightarrow X^*$in$L^1$.So I want to say that it maybe true.